# SimpleDateFormat parse time function in objective c

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c, ios, date-format

I am making replica of an android application, there is code for time

```
SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss MMddyyyy");
Date noteTime = myDateFormat.parse("235959 12319999");
```

I want the objective-c code which produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"HHmmss MMddyyyy"];
        NSDate *finalDate =[formatter1 dateFromString:@"235959 12319999"];
        [formatter1 release];
```

For getting in NSString

```
NSString *finalDateString =[formatter1 stringFromDate:finalDate];
```

Comment: and how to get it in the form of NSString ?